# ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError FATAL: database "db/development.postgresql" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm building a small app and it was working locally. Then when I went to deploy it on Heroku, this error popped up in my terminal:

```
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and 

Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pockettheskimm.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/pockettheskimm.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I subsequently [read the documentation on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), which told me that I have to use Postgres in my app instead of sqlite3. So I updated my app, swapping out sqlite3 for Postgres:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.postgresql

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.postgresql

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.postgresql
```

but now when I run the app locally, I get this error in my browser:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: database "db/development.postgresql" does not exist

Extracted source (around line #661):
659
660
661
662
663
664

        rescue ::PG::Error => error
          if error.message.include?("does not exist")
            raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError.new(error.message, error)
          else
            raise
          end
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You should read documentation carefully https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#running-rails-on-postgres
`db/development.postgresql` syntax is not allowed by postgres

Comment: Have you ran `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` on development after you've change your `database.yml` config file?

Comment: This is what the issue, was- thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This was the answer that worked for me:

"Have you ran `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` on development after you've change your database.yml config file? "

credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/163640/eugen

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```sh
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the gem that has `sqlite3` as a dependency and remove it from your `Gemfile`.Once you’ve done this run `bundle install` and ensure that `sqlite3` no longer exists in your `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 0):

try not using
anything
in your gem file until everything has proccesed
otherwise
ActiveRecord will function differently

Answer (score -1):

Some initialiser should be using the DB before it is created, so the `db:create` breaks.

To fix the error in the root cause, fix the initialisers and your lib settings.

ps: In my case, it was the FactoryBot.